# socket.on('disconnect') gets triggered randomly and repeats forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, socket.io

I am using socket.io to make a basic chat application, based on the one from [their website](https://socket.io/get-started/chat). To start off, I implemented some code that when the disconnect event is triggered, sends a message to all the other clients that someone has disconnected.

When I connect to the server with the client, after a while, it starts sending the message 'x has left the chat' even though no one has left the chat. In addition, if I open two clients and one disconnects this will also happen to the other one. How do I prevent this from happening randomly, and when someone does disconnect, how do I cause it to trigger only once?

This is how the server looks:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    io.emit('chat message', 'x has left the chat');
    socket.disconnect(true)
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

I did add the line `socket.disconnect(true)` to try to make sure that the it completely disconnects, but this doesn't help. The client is the same as on the website:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
        });
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: in your html, form.submit means reload the html?  socket.io disconnect when the html reload or you 'go' to another html page.  In my previous chat app/chat website, I use SPA so that the user remains at the same 'parent html page', i.e. the index.html.  When user click some buttons or a message from the server arrived, I only refresh the childs of the index.html, without reloading it.  So I never got the disconnect event unless the user close the browser/press F5 to reload the page/or quit the Andriod/iphone app.  (I'm using Cordova, app runs in mobile phone and PC browsers)

Comment: No it doesn't reload the page because it keeps the previous chat messages.